# Changing image in Chrome with jQuery don't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$('#logo a img').attr('src', window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/images/loader.gif');
```

It's jQuery. It is made to change the image to the loader, it works in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome it appears that: http://gyazo.com/6dad40741782b122cf621716ff2b86ec
I've tried to load it with the url and Chrome finds the image, but it just don't load in the page. What can be the reason? It just works when you click 'Log in', I don't know why because it's the same function...
Thank you so much!

P.S: Sorry for my bad english ;(

P.S 2: I don't want to use CSS if it's possible, thanks

Here's the live Demo, just click the logo (for example): http://www.sploonder.com/

Comment: Symptom: `CTRL + Click` or `Command + Click` on the logo to open in a new tab and the loading logo image will display and not change.

Comment: It's because you're navigating away on click - you can't replace the image and still have the link go somewhere. Why don't you want to use CSS? It would solve the problem quite nicely.

Comment: Okey, I'll do it with with css... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you preload the loader image before use it.

Just run this code when the document is ready.

```
$('<img>').attr('src', window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/images/loader.gif');
```

And try it again.

Comment: @maduranma Tip: You can set an answer as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick below it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution (preloading the image), it worked just sometimes, so I had to use CSS.